# Distinct join query

Tags: sql

Possible silly question, but got me stumped. Compare 2 tables and return only distinct columns.

```
        SELECT DISTINCT(DM.CLIENT_CODE) FROM DBO.DM_CLIENT DM
        LEFT JOIN DBO.STG_DM_CLIENT STG
        ON STG.CLIENT_CODE = DM.CLIENT_CODE
```

Aim of query is to return only new client_codes from DM table (or client_codes not listed in STG table).

I tought this would work, however does not.

can this query be then used in a case query to validate when new codes exists, then set resultset to 'A'

```
       select  case 
            when (SELECT DBO.DM_CLIENT.Client_Code  
            FROM DBO.DM_CLIENT DM  
            LEFT JOIN DBO.STG_DM_CLIENT STG    
          ON STG.Client_Code= DM.Client_Code  
            WHERE STG.Client_Code IS NULL  
          GROUP BY  DM.Client_Code) then 'A'
       end

       from  DBO.DM_CLIENT.Client_Code, DBO.STG_DM_CLIENT.Client_Code
```

How can I make that statement to be a conditional statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to return those from DM that don't exist in STG.

```
 SELECT DM.Client_Code
 FROM DBO.DM_CLIENT As DM
 LEFT JOIN DBO.STG_DM_CLIENT As STG 
   ON STG.Client_Code= DM.Client_Code
 WHERE STG.Client_Code IS NULL
 GROUP BY  DM.Client_Code;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the query to exclude records where the join failed.

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT(DM.CLIENT_CODE)
FROM
    DBO.DM_CLIENT AS DM
    LEFT OUTER JOIN DBO.STG_DM_CLIENT AS STG ON
        STG.CLIENT_CODE = DM.CLIENT_CODE
WHERE
    STG.CLIENT_CODE IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

That query is, actually, returning all client_codes.

Try this one instead.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT(DM.CLIENT_CODE) FROM DBO.DM_CLIENT DM
     WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM DBO.STG_DM_CLIENT STG
        WHERE STG.CLIENT_CODE = DM.CLIENT_CODE
     );
```

The query [mikerobi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571589/distinct-join-query/7571627#7571627) proposed is better on efficiency than this one.

Comment: No, the query is returning all DM.CLIENT_CODE values whether *or not* they're in STG.

Comment: @LarryLustig Fixed, thank you. I don't know what I was thinking about.

Answer (score 0):

Try either:

```
select distinct dm.client_code
from dbo.dm_client dm
left join dbo.stg_dm_client stg on stg.client_code = dm.client_code
where stg.client_code is null
```

Or:

```
select distinct dm.client_code
from dbo.dm_client dm
where not exists (select null from stg.client_code stg where dm.client_code = stg.client_code)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CLIENT_CODE
  FROM DBO.DM_CLIENT
EXCEPT
SELECT CLIENT_CODE
  FROM DBO.STG_DM_CLIENT;
```

Change `EXCEPT` to `MINUS` if you are using Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in different ways:

**Using NOT IN**

```
SELECT *
FROM DM_CLIENT
WHERE client_code NOT IN (
    SELECT client_code
    FROM STG_DM_CLIENT 
)
```

**Using EXISTS**

```
SELECT *
FROM DM_CLIENT dm
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT client_code
    FROM STG_DM_CLIENT
    WHERE client_code=dm.client_code
)
```

**Using LEFT or RIGHT JOIN**

```
SELECT dm.* 
FROM DM_CLIENT DM
LEFT JOIN STG_DM_CLIENT STG
     ON STG.CLIENT_CODE = DM.CLIENT_CODE
WHERE stg.client_code is null
```

In SQL Server 2005 or newer versions you can use [OUTER APPLY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156.aspx) or [EXCEPT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx)